# Node's console.log() outputs an object's info. How do I output it to a file?

Tags: node.js

I like how `console.log(object)` will output `object`'s structure in json format. How do I make my app output the same stuff to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Golo said there is nothing built-in in Node for that but you can easily write your own (or use Winston) :)

```
fs = require('fs');

logToFile = function(fileName, objectToLog) {

  jsonText = JSON.stringify(objectToLog, null, '\t');
  fs.writeFileSync(fileName, jsonText, 'utf8');      

}

sampleData = { name: 'Batman', city: 'Gotham' };
logToFile('log.txt', sampleData);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not out of the box support for file logging in Node.js.

Basically, you have two options:

1. You can redirect any output of the Node.js process to a file by using the mechanisms of your operating system to redirect streams.
2. Use a dedicated logging library, such as [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston).

I'd go with the second option as it's the more flexible one and you'll need it sooner or later, at least if your project gets slightly bigger.