# How to log JavaScript objects and arrays in winston as console.log does?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, logging, winston

I was looking at top Node logging systems: `npmlog`, `log4js`, `bunyan` and `winston` and decided to use `winston` for having the most `npm` monthly downloads.

What I want to set up is custom logger which I will be able to use on development environment with `logger.debug(...)` which won't log anything on production environment. This will help me so when I'm on development environment, I won't need to write anything since I'll see all the outputs.

This is what I have now:

```
var level = 'debug';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'){
  level = 'production'; // this will never be logged!
}

var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    // some other loggings
    new winston.transports.Console({
      name: 'debug-console',
      level: level,
      prettyPrint: true,
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      colorize: true
    })

  ],
  exitOnError: false // don't crush no error
});
```

Problem occurs when I'm trying to log JavaScript `Object` or Javascript `Array`. With `Object`, I need to do `toJSON()`, and for `Array` I need first `JSON.stringify()` and then `JSON.parse()`.

It's not nice to write all the time this methods, just to log something that I want. Furthermore, it's not even resource-friendly, because those formatting methods need to be executed before `logger.debug()` realises that it's on production and that it shouldn't log it in the first place (basically, it's evaluating arguments before function call). I just like how old-fashined `console.log()` logs JavaScript objects and arrays.

Now, as I'm writing this question, I found that there is a way of describing [custom format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#custom-log-format) for every winston `transports` object. Is that the way of doing it, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try changing prettyPrint parameter to

```
prettyPrint: function ( object ){
    return JSON.stringify(object);
}
```

Comment: Fun fact, you can also do `prettyPrint: JSON.stringify`

Comment: Wont this fail if `object` has circular reference?

Comment: Yes absolutely it will fail in circular JSON. I have added an answer where I resolved the problem by using util.format function.

Answer (score 31):

```
logger.log("info", "Starting up with config %j", config);
```

Winstons uses the built-in utils.format library.
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args

Comment: Provide some explanation to your answer to why it works like this or what the OP was doing wrong. Just a code paste like this gets flagged.

Comment: Best solution I've seen here. Uses the existing logger api and prints everything pretty.

Comment: Just a reminder, you need to have format.splat() enabled. Otherwise it does not work.

Answer (score 8):

In Winston > 3 you can use

```
logger.log('%o', { lol: 123 }')
```

Anyway...
Couldn't accept that I have to use %o always and made this simple solution:

```
const prettyJson = format.printf(info => {
  if (info.message.constructor === Object) {
    info.message = JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 4)
  }
  return `${info.level}: ${info.message}`
})

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.colorize(),
    format.prettyPrint(),
    format.splat(),
    format.simple(),
    prettyJson,
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console({})
  ],
})
```

So this logger....

```
  logger.info({ hi: 123 })
```

...transforms to this in the console

```
info: {
    "hi": 123
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your answer won't work with: `log.silly(\`Ok: ${{ lol: 123 }}\`);` :(

Comment: @K-ToxicityinSOisgrowing. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @FabZbi I created my own log library: https://github.com/langurama/log

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in Node.js function `util.format` to convert your objects to strings in the same way that `console.log` does.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to write your own abstraction on top of winston that has a convenience method for printing your objects for debugging.

You may also look at this response for a hint of how the method could be developed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620543/2211743

Answer (score 1):

As Leo already pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46973676/964160), Winston makes use of [String Interpolation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#string-interpolation) provided by [util.format](https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/util.html#util.format):

```
const winston = require("winston");                                                                                                                                                                                                    
const logger = new winston.Logger({                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  transports: [                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    // some other loggings                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    new winston.transports.Console({                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      name: "debug-console",                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      level: process.env.LOGLEVEL || "info",                                                                                                                                                                                           
      prettyPrint: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      handleExceptions: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      json: false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      colorize: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  exitOnError: false // don't crush no error                                                                                                                                                                                           
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

const nestedObj = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  foo: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    bar: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      baz: "example"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

const myString = "foo";                                                                                                                                                                                                                

logger.log("info", "my nested object: %j. My string: %s", nestedObj, myString);
```

When calling `logger.log`, you can define placeholders which will be appropriately replaced. `%j` will be replaced by the equivalent of `JSON.stringify(nestedObj)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using util.inspect for objects. It handles circular references correctly as well. @radon-rosborough has already given this answer but I thought of adding an example. Please see below

```
const customTransports = [
    new winston.transports.Console({
        format: combine(
            timestamp({
                format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS'
            }),
            label({
                label: file
            }),
            prettyPrint(),
            format.splat(),
            simple(),
            printf( (msg)=> {
                let message = msg.message;

                return colorize().colorize(msg.level, `${ msg.level } :  ${msg.timestamp} :  ${ msg.label } : \n`) + `${ util.inspect(message,{
                    depth: 2,
                    compact:true,
                    colors: true,
                } )}`;
            })
        )
    })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
prettyPrint: function ( object ){
    return JSON.stringify(object)
}
```

it's better go with [utils-deep-clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utils-deep-clone) package

```
// initialize package on the top
const { toJSON } = require('utils-deep-clone')


// and now in your `prettyPrint` parameter do this
prettyPrint: function ( object ){
    return toJSON(object)
}
```

if you'll go with `JSON.stringify` you won't be able to print error

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('some error')))
// output will '{}'
```